# Why doesn't this bash script print stdout on console when run as sudo?

Tags: bash, stdout, sudo, stderr, tee

Consider the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define a function to redirect both stdout and stderr
redirect_both_to() {
    local log_file=logfile.log
    exec > >(tee -a "$log_file") 2> >(tee -a "$log_file")
}


# Example functions
one() {
    echo "This is from one()"
    echo "Error message from one()"
}

two() {
    echo "This is from two()"
    echo "Error message from two()"
}

# Call the functions
function main(){
    redirect_both_to
    one
    two
}

main "$@"
```

When this script is executed without `sudo`, the output is displayed on the console and it is written to the log file (as expected). However, if I run the same script as root (i.e., `sudo ./script.sh`), the script exits without printing anything to the console. But both `stdout` and `stderr` are correctly recorded in the log file. Ultimately, I want the script to be run as `sudo`.

Comment: This happens because bash exits before `tee`s. Add `sleep .1` after `main "$@"` and you'll see. You can do `exec > >(tee -a "$log_file") 2>&1` instead and `wait` at the end of the script, or ditch `redirect_both_to` and do `{ main "$@" | tee -a stdout.log;} 2>&1 | tee -a stderr.log`.

Comment: Wow, that was it indeed. If you want to submit your comment as an answer, go for it. Thanks heaps. Follow-up: why does bash exit before `tee` only when it's run as `sudo`? Why does it print everything as expected when it's run without `sudo`?

Comment: At least in my case, bash does not exit *before* the `tee`s, but shortly *after*. You can check this with `sudo bash -x ./script.sh`. Also, *sometimes* `./script.sh` (without sudo) *seems* to hang after printing all messages. The script actually terminates, but my interactive bash shell prints the next prompt *before* the output of the script. When you look after the output, and there is no prompt, you are fooled into thinking the script would still run.

Comment: Bash exits early in both cases, it never waits for process substitutions to exit (and only remembers the most recently started one, hence my suggestion with only one process substitution and `wait`). You're not seeing any output with `sudo` because, **I think**,`sudo` somehow prevents the output of a privileged process from landing on an unprivileged TTY, which makes sense as a security measure. I'm not posting an answer because it'd be too long and inaccurate.

Comment: @Socowi Yes, I should have said *bash exits without waiting for `tee`s*.